# Why do variables are stored in an inverted order than the declaration order

Tags: c, memory

I was debugging a program when I found out that if I declared two variables, foo and then bar, and if I watched the memory with a debugger, foo is stored after bar.

For instance, if I debug this program:

```
int main()
{
    char foo[6] = "hello";
    char bar[12] = "hello world";
    return 0;
}
```

GDB tells me that `bar` begins at `0x7fffffffe6ae` and ends 13 chars later, and `foo` begins at `0x7fffffffe6ba` and ends 6 characters later, so the address of `foo` is greater than the `bar` address.

So why `foo` is stored after `bar` in memory, even if `foo` is declared before `bar`?

Comment: The compiler can make the decision on local variable storage , the standard does not require any ordering. You might see different behaviour in other compilers

Comment: Depends on your point of view anyway. If the stack grows downwards, then `foo` was stored first.